# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.shortcuts'

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I am creating a bookstore website using the Django framework and this error can't be resolved after various StackOverflow previous solutions.

```
File "E:\django\bookstore\book\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
  File "E:\django\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
  File "E:\django\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.shortcuts import resolve_url
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.shortcuts'
```

This is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import login,logout,authenticate
from .models import *
from .forms import *
```

Apart from this, I also have 2 venv config files in the env directory. what should I do about them — should one of them be deleted?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`django.shortcuts` is not the `django-shortcuts` package. It is this:

[image]

If your `django` package does not contain it, could you try to reinstall the `django`?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are right. I totally missed that.

Comment: Sorry I can't, I upvoted it. But Mohit Aggarwal can accept, He Asked the Question.

Comment: @Faisal Nazik haha, sorry for that.